# userform multicolumn listbox not showing records unless form is closed and re-opened

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have 4 user input forms where user inputs/edits records via fields on the form and the records display below in a multi-column listbox. (There are also Save and Delete buttons on the forms.) They have all worked fine for weeks of unit testing. Now that I have coded and debugged the calculations part of the project, I have started a final round of system testing where I am starting with blank data sheets. And the listboxes are showing a strange (new) behavior.

When I open a form with no records, enter the first record and save it, the record is not displayed. The record does get saved properly on the data sheets. The first column of the listbox displays the record number and the rest of the columns are blank. However, I am not including (displaying) the record number (column A) on the forms. I only display values from columns 2 the 7 (B thru H) of the data sheet. It will only show the record number for every record I enter thereafter, as long as I am in the same "session" of the open form when I entered the first record.

However, if I close the form and re-open it, the records displays as they should. And any subsequent records I enter after I re-open the form, the new records also display properly. Even if I delete all the records on the form and ad new ones, they display fine as long as I have not closed the form. This behavior is the same for all 4 of the forms. The forms all worked properly when I created them, and for literally a couple of months of unit testing after that. Admittedly, I have made a lot of code changes to correct errors I have found in the calculations part of my project. But I cannot conceive of any that would globally affect listboxes on all the forms.

Example code for one of the forms Initialize event:

```
        If Not iAcctLastRow = 1 Then 'there are no records to load into listbox
            Set rAcctDB = wsAcctInput.Range("A2:J" & iAcctLastRow)
            With Me.lstAcct 'Populate listbox
                .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
                .Font.Size = 10
                .ColumnCount = 10
                .ColumnWidths = "0,120,80,90,60,60,80,60,0,0"
                .List = rAcctDB.Cells.Value
            End With
        End If
```

And in the Save procedure I refresh the listbox as follows:

```
        iAcctLastRow = wsAcctInput.Range("B22").End(xlUp).row
        DelayThis 50 'added this delay but no change
        Set rAcctDB = wsAcctInput.Range("A2:J" & iAcctLastRow)
        Me.lstAcct.List = rAcctDB.Cells.Value 'Refresh listbox
```

The above code is the same on all 4 forms, varying in which data sheet and columns being used. I can repeat the above behaviors at will. Has anyone seen this before, or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent all day on this. I cannot answer why this changed, but I can explain how I fixed it. I noticed that the listbox not only was showing just the row number, but it was only loading that single column as if there was only supposed to be 1 column.  The listbox object has ColumnCount and ColumnWidths that can be set in the Object Browser. My ColumnCount has always been set to 1 and ColumnWidths being blank, because I set them in code. So I changed the Object Browser ColumnCount to 10 and pasted my widths into ColumnWidths. And it worked. I set them back to the defaults of 1 and blank, respectively. I saw the earlier failure to load the listbox columns.

The fix was to force the column count and widths again with each Save via code just as I do in the userform initialization, instead of the simple range refresh.

```
            With Me.lstAcct 'Populate listbox
                .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
                .Font.Size = 10
                .ColumnCount = 10
                .ColumnWidths = "0,120,80,90,60,60,80,60,0,0"
                .List = rAcctDB.Cells.Value
            End With
```

I have a backup of this file from 3 months ago with the code working as it is shown in the original post, and the column counts and widths set to their default values - which is why I had not tried this fix earlier. I cannot explain what changed in the code execution. Nor can I explain why it only worked properly if there was at least one record in the listbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the listbox on initialize even if there are no records to show.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim wsAcctInput As Worksheet, iAcctLastRow As Long
    Set wsAcctInput = Sheet1
    iAcctLastRow = wsAcctInput.Range("B22").End(xlUp).Row

    With Me.lstAcct 'Populate listbox
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .Font.Size = 10
        .ColumnCount = 10
        .ColumnWidths = "0,120,80,90,60,60,80,60,0,0"
        If iAcctLastRow > 1 Then
            .List = wsAcctInput.Range("A2:J" & iAcctLastRow).Value
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, that doe not solve the issue, but it is a nice little tweak. Thanks.